# How to fix CORS for Capacitor/Quasar App in a Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, cors, capacitor, quasar-framework

I have an App built on top of Quasar and Capacitor, with an API built on top of Laravel. Everything works well on the dev environment until I build and install the app on my phone, then I keep getting timeouts, decided to build a SPA and run it with Liteserver and it turns out that the server was returning an: "`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://smk.toneflix.com.ng/api/pages/about' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`" error.

On my Kernel.php I do have this:

```php
protected $middleware = [
    // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

And on my cors.php config file, I also have this:

```php
return [
    'paths' => ['*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

I also have this in my sanctum.php config

```php
return [
    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort(),
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : '',
        env('FRONTEND_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('FRONTEND_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),
    ...
]
```

I've tried several other configuration options, and suggestions from other SO answers, but non is helping.
Everything works in Postman and if I create a subdomain on the API domain and host an SPA, but that is not what I want, I need requests to go through on the native app when running on a real device.

**EDIT**

I figured out that my device makes requests from `https://localhost`, so I added that to the `FRONTEND_URL` Environment variable, and it worked, but I do understand that this is not sustainable given that I do not have control over where my apps will run, so I don't consider that to be a fix.

**FOR CONTEXT**

Here is my default axios setup:

```js
let headers = {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
  "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
  "SameSite": "None",
};

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/",
  headers,
});
```

**UPDATE**

Taylor Otwell was actually on this question after I mentioned him on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/marxemi/status/1663704066348703746), it's a long thread and a lot of people offered help, after an Anydesk session with another Twitter user we concluded that it might be a server issue since everything seems to work well on dev setup even with the live API, I'll try other deployment options to see what works, and update as necessary.

**ONE LAST UPDATE**

It's been 3 days and 2 days past my delivery deadline, Turns out everything was working perfectly, and my phone was for reasons I don't yet know messing things up. I decided to run the app on the [Appetize](https://appetize.io/) Platform and it performed flawlessly. Thanks to everyone who contributed to help me out in these pressing times.
Peace.

Comment: What _exactly_ is the error message? Don't paraphrase or abhreviate - it's really unhelpful

Comment: Sorry for the misrepresentation, I have now updated my question.

Comment: @3m1n3nc3 Please edit your question and add the full declaration for `$middleware`. Your issue likely stems from your stacking of the various middleware in an incorrect order.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full middleware declaration.

Comment: Is `https://smk.toneflix.com.ng/api/pages/about` your domain? The error pretty clearly says the problem is a missing header on "the requested resource." So unless you control that resource, not sure what you can do. I have little experience with CORS though, so may be misunderstanding.

Comment: I control the resource, `toneflix.com.ng` is my domain. I created the smk subdomain to hold the API.

Comment: I've updated the question to include my js implementation.

Comment: What is the response from the preflight? Most situations I come across with Access Origin restrictions is because the Preflight failed, but if the response doesn't return a "ok status" you will get that message regardless. The response in your question isn't the response from your server, it's proxy browser message for when it doesn't get the "ok status". I would check your server/Laravel logs first.

Answer (score 0):

Your cors.php config file should look like this:

```
return [

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false, //This can be true or false

];
```

On your kernel.php file remove `\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,` and use `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,`

Add this `"fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",` to your composer.json file, then run `composer install`

Then, remove some of the header objects on your Axios, and allow Axios to set them for you unless you want to customize them. For instance:

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/",
  headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, //This is optional
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
});
```

Ensure you restart your laravel local server after doing all this.